# How can I set tor to use a proxy file (.pac)

Tags: mac, proxy

I need a proxy file (.pac) to access the internet. I used to work with a HTTP/HTTPS proxy which is easily configured through Tor settings but now I have to use a .pac file, and I can't find the option in the initial configuration.

Images :

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the answer to this is quite simple :

I needed to download the .pac file (provided by the company I'm consulting for). Next I had to open it and locate the url and the port they're using for the .pac configuration file

[image]

and configure tor to use an HTTP/HTTPS proxy as usual.